# Was rapeseed oil used for cooking before the twentieth century?

Tags: food

[The Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapeseed_oil) on rapeseed oil states that it has been in use for thousands of years, starting in India around 4,000 years ago and China and Japan around 2,000 years ago. However, it is unclear if it was originally used for food or only for other purposes such as burning in lamps.

There is no explicit mention of when it was first eaten except that it was introduced into food products in the 1950s despite suffering from multiple undesirable characteristics.

Is there a history of using rapeseed as an edible oil prior to that?

Comment: [The Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapeseed_oil) reports `documentation of its use in India 4,000 years ago, and use in China and Japan 2,000 years ago` with a footnote on the source, and other sources are easily found. The linguistic question will require someone with language skills but I would consider it off-topic.

Comment: @BrianZ In the next sentence the wp article says that rape seed oil has historically been used as fuel in oil lamps. Question is about use as a cooking ingredient, not about use as fuel.

Comment: @TylerDurden I've completely rewritten the question to focus on the central relevant fact not addressed in the Wikipedia article. If you object please explain... Where are you seeing these allegations about "surplus waste products", why focus on China, etc.

Comment: An article [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=wKWulH2TFh4C&lpg=PR11&pg=PA54#v=onepage&q&f=false) discusses use as lubricant, not food oil. Another article [here](https://www.ocl-journal.org/articles/ocl/full_html/2016/06/ocl160045s/ocl160045s.html) goes into historic use of *brassica* as a food, but again not as a food oil. An article I lost the link on mentioned that the oil was allowed to be consumed by the public due to its use in china 'for centuries', so focus on China usage seems logical to validate saftey claims made early on. (I'll try to find that article...)

Comment: A pdf from Cornell [here](https://ecommons.cornell.edu/server/api/core/bitstreams/5a03999b-10df-44a8-9d78-121c06e89e1a/content) says *Initially they reported that rats fed high levels of rapeseed oil performed poorly under stress and had enlarged adrenals.to counter these reports, it was pointed out that asian peoples had consumed rapeseed oil for centuries with no ill effects. Thus, the domestic market was allowed to grow.*

Comment: The German WP article on [Raps](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raps#Geschichte_der_Rapsnutzung) hints at its use for food "in times of hunger" since the 17th century, but remains vague. The first claim of a fact is that is was used in margarine during WWI. The quoted sources are not available online.

Comment: Marvelous salvaging of the question, flipping my vote from down to up

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is apparently yes but the details are quite hazy. What even is rapeseed in the first place? *[The Cambridge World History of Food](https://www.cambridge.org/us/universitypress/cambridge-world-history-food)* says:

> The term “rapeseed” is used for any oil-bearing Brassica seed, including that of mustard.

[The genus *Brassica*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brassica) includes a long list of common vegetables from broccoli and bok choi to cabbage and turnips, and there are several known hybrids between species. Some sources seem to reserve the term rapeseed for specific oilseed cultivars but it's often unclear.

The *Cambridge World History* mentions that the "use of rapeseed oil for food and illumination originated in Asia (later spreading to the Mediterranean and Europe)" but provides no further details or references.

[An article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0065229607450017) titled simply "History, Origin, and Evolution" focuses on India and claims (in rather convoluted English):

> Two species, B. juncea and B. campestris having a range of morphotypes, are the crops of antiquity in India where much before the Christian era, they were used for many purposes including oil for cooking and frying, spice for seasoning food articles, vegetables, and for religious ceremonies (Mehra, 1966).

The term "rape" is related to turnips or *Brassica rapa*, [whose morphotypes include both turnips and oilseed crops](https://academic.oup.com/mbe/article/38/8/3358/6261082). Canola, popular for cooking oil today, is a cross of *Brassica rapa* and *Brasica napa* developed in the 1970s.

In a comment, JustCal links to [an article](https://www.ocl-journal.org/articles/ocl/full_html/2016/06/ocl160045s/ocl160045s.html#R13) that includes a detailed paragraph on the history of Brassica crops in China. It's clear that several were considered oilseed crops in ancient times, but there is nothing there about whether the oil was consumed as food.

There's an interesting account from 16th century Europe:

> In Germany, a comprehensive account of winter rapeseed production
> in the Rhineland area dates from 1570 with the oil being used as a lamp oil, a cheaper alternative to olive oil, and as a cooking fat in “a poor man’s kitchen.”

I've seen this attributed to [Heresbach](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A03069.0001.001) but I've not found the exact reference, nor have I seen any guesses on what species this might have been.

Overall, I think it's safe to say that oils of various Brassica species have been consumed in various times and places. If you want to know about any particular species, the story may be difficult to trace.

Comment: Two handbooks from the 19th century ([Hildebrand](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Handbuch_des_landwirtschaftlichen_Pflanz/_NJBAAAAIAAJ?pg=PA375) and [Langethal](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Handbuch_der_landwirthschaftlichen_Pflan/mrh-AAAAIAAJ?pg=RA2-PA98)) date the introduction of Raps (Brassica napus olifera) in the Rhineland to the 18th century. Before that, [Rübsen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ölrübsen) (Brassica rapa olifera) was planted.